# eclipse compile error: Error in JDT Core during AST creation

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

After updating to the latest eclipse Luna and Java JDK release I suddenly have the following eclipse compiler error marked at a package declaration at one of our classes:

The Event-Details from the problems view show following information:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
java.version=1.8.0_40
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -clean -showlocation -data C:\workspaces\blub

This is a continuation of log file C:\workspaces\blub\.metadata\.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2015-03-09 11:43:33.242

org.eclipse.jdt.ui
Error
Mon Mar 09 11:50:01 CET 2015
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jdt.ui".

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.SingleNameReference.analyseCode(SingleNameReference.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.analyseCode(MessageSend.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.analyseCode(LocalDeclaration.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Block.analyseCode(Block.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LambdaExpression.analyseCode(LambdaExpression.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.analyseCode(MessageSend.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Block.analyseCode(Block.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.IfStatement.analyseCode(IfStatement.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Block.analyseCode(Block.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.WhileStatement.analyseCode(WhileStatement.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Block.analyseCode(Block.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LambdaExpression.analyseCode(LambdaExpression.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.SingleNameReference.analyseAssignment(SingleNameReference.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Assignment.analyseCode(Assignment.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ConstructorDeclaration.analyseCode(ConstructorDeclaration.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.internalAnalyseCode(TypeDeclaration.java:733)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.analyseCode(TypeDeclaration.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.analyseCode(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnitResolver.resolve(CompilationUnitResolver.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnitResolver.resolve(CompilationUnitResolver.java:689)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.internalCreateAST(ASTParser.java:1183)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.createAST(ASTParser.java:809)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ASTProvider$1.run(ASTProvider.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ASTProvider.createAST(ASTProvider.java:537)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ASTProvider.getAST(ASTProvider.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.SharedASTProvider.getAST(SharedASTProvider.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.NLSStringHover.internalGetHoverInfo(NLSStringHover.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.NLSStringHover.getHoverInfo2(NLSStringHover.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:166)
```

Fortunatly I was able to extract a small example out of the project to reproduce this error. The code itself does not make much sense anymore but its valid java code and it shows the eclipse compiler error:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.PathElement;

public class LogicalPathDriver
{
  private final ListChangeListener<PathElement> synchronizeLogicalPathWithElements;
  private final Path                            representation;

  private Map<PathElement, PathElement>         realToLogicalElementsMapping;

  public LogicalPathDriver()
  {
    this.representation = new Path();

    synchronizeLogicalPathWithElements = change ->
    {
      while ( change.next() )
      {
        if ( change.wasRemoved() )
        {
          final List<? extends PathElement> removed = change.getRemoved();
          removed.forEach( removedElement ->
          {
            final PathElement logicalElement = realToLogicalElementsMapping.get( removedElement );
            Objects.requireNonNull( change );
            representation.getElements().remove( logicalElement );
          } );
        }
      }
    };
  }
}
```

There are a few solutions to fix this:

1. Using anonymous classes instead of lambda.
2. Changing the scope of representation to a local variable.
3. Commenting out the content of the forEach Statement.

Before adding this to the eclipse bug tracker I wanted to be sure, that this is a real bug, or if I am missing anything here.

Comment: Latest Eclipse Luna =  "Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)"?

Comment: Correct, I am using eclipse luna 4.4.2, no further updates available (from the in-update mechanism)

Comment: Possibly bug [446691](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=446691)

Comment: @greg-449: Yes, seems like it has already been reported there.

Comment: @greg-449 this indeed looks like the same issue, thank you.